# SQL get customers by age

Tags: sql, sql-server

How i can get a list of customers, whose age will be 5 or 10 years on a given interval of two dates ?

The query for only one date is:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers C  
WHERE DATEDIFF(MONTH,C.StartDate,@Date)=60  
OR DATEDIFF(MONTH, C.StartDate,@Date)=120
```

Comment: Must know what database this is for "sql" does not tell use enough. Looks like SQL Server. Is it?

Comment: Its SQ Server 2012.

Answer (score 4):

You want customers where they are 5 or less at the start and 5 or greater at the end - this means that at some point in the range they were 5.

```
SELECT * FROM Customers C
WHERE (DATEDIFF(MONTH,C.StartDate,@StartDate)<=60 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH,C.StartDate,@EndDate) >=60)
    OR (DATEDIFF(MONTH,C.StartDate,@StartDate)<=120 AND DATEDIFF(MONTH,C.StartDate,@EndDate) >=120)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a query like below
<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/DKXLWG58315)**</kbd>

```
DECLARE @Date1 DATE
DECLARE @Date2 DATE
SET @Date1='03-19-2017'
SET @Date2='12-19-2017'

SELECT * FROM Customers C  
WHERE ( DATEADD(m,  60,C.StartDate) BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2 )
 OR 
(DATEADD(m, 120,C.StartDate) BETWEEN @Date1 AND @Date2)
```

Comment: Thanks. 
I think i need to use the datediff, because I´m not considering the days in the Date1 and Date2.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of T-SQL's datediff function is:

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

The order of dates IS important, to get a positive integer result the earlier date should be first and the later date should be second. If you do it the other way the results will be negative numbers.

You can overcome this by using ABS()

```
ABS( DATEDIFF ( datepart , date1 , date2 )  )
```